# One Time Password Mobile phone authentication

Tags: passwords, mobile, one-time-password, smartphone

Can the Mobile phone One Time Password authentication be alphanumeric with special characters?

If Yes, There will be more pros and less cons with increased security?

[One Time password](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password)

Can a One Time Password decimal number increase security?

Examples: 143.45, 378.21, 7621.10, 8712.45 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which One-Time Password scheme you're talking about, but if you mean the widely used HMAC-based One-Time Password (HOTP) or Time-based One-Time Password (TOTP), then the answer is no.

[According to the RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4226#section-5.3), both HOTP and TOTP generate a four-byte value which is expressed as an integer in the range `0 ... 2^31 - 1` or `0 ... 2147483647`. That's at most 10 digits.

You could, in principle, convert the four-byte value into something alphanumeric with special characters, but this wouldn't increase security, of course -- and it would be inconvenient and violate the specification.

The reason why HOTP/TOTP generates short digit sequences is that the OTPs are only valid for a short time and need to be typed in quickly. It wouldn't make sense to have a very long OTP with all kinds of special characters. Of course it would be possible to create a scheme where the OTPs are valid for a longer time but more complex. However, this would be very inconvenient for the user.

Comment: Thanks. So the Complex OTP can be created but valid for a longer time.

Comment: Yes, but I wouldn't recommend it. Use a standard TOTP/HOTP implementation and let your users *combine* the OTP with a complex password. Nobody wants to type in some long random string whenever they log in.

Comment: Thanks. Can a One Time Password decimal number increase security?

Examples: 143.45, 378.21, 7621.10, 8712.45 etc

Comment: No. An OTP is always a sequence of 4 bytes.Whether you display those bytes as an integer or as a decimal number with a fractional part makes no difference for security. It's still the same data. The only difference is that you've added a dot between the digits, which in this case is entirely useless. To increase security, you'd have to increase the number of bytes, which is non-standard and therefore not recommended. Just to clarify: There's generally no need to increase the security of OTPs. Since they're only valid for a very short time (e.g., 30 seconds), it's fine if they're simple.